# Add two quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a code like this :

```js
 var event = {
  "temperature" : 12.45,
  "humidite" : 45.78,
  "built" : "charone",
  "fire" : "chartwo",
  "topic" : "sk1_001/data"
 };
 
var keys = Object.keys(event);
 
 valeurs_d = ""; 
 for (var i = 0; i < keys.length -1 ; i++) 
 valeurs_d += event[keys[i]] + ", "; 
 var str5 = ","; 
 var str6 = str5.concat(valeurs_d); 
 var valeurs = str6.substring (0, str6.length - 2);  console.log(valeurs);
```

I want to have everything between two quotes in variable `valeurs` like this:

```
, '12 .45 ', '45 .78', 'charone', 'chartwo'
```

Or, just have the character strings between two quotes:

```
, 12.45, 45.78, 'charone', 'chartwo'
```

I can have in my JSON other strings.

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Not clear what expected result is?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear... the values you're asking about are already in quotes, are they not?

Comment: OP wants the quotes to also be included in the string.

Comment: No, the result is : ,12.45, 45.78, charone, chartwo

Comment: Can you include expected result at as code Question?

Comment: > I want to have everything between two quotes in variable valeurs like this :," '12 .45 ', '45 .78', 'charone', 'chartwo'" > the result is : "12.45, 45.78, charone, chartwo"

Comment: Why is there a leading comma `,` at  expected result?

Comment: guest271314, because I generate a query to insert in database

Comment: Not related to question, but I think most of the languages supports query building stuff which takes care of datatype

Comment: Not related to question. I have a problem with the Typeof in Javascript which returns number or string. The Apache Cassandra database only accepts varchar for string, and I want to set double for number. How do I proceed ?

Comment: If you have another question, please use the Ask Question button to ask another question. Comments are meant to be only about the post.

Comment: Be very careful when generating insert statements using string concatenation, especially via a front-end JavaScript (it's not clear if this is front-end or back-end), as that way leads to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the type and add some quotes around.

```js
var event = { temperature : 12.45, humidite : 45.78, built : "charone", fire : "chartwo", topic : "sk1_001/data" },
    result = ',' + Object
        .keys(event)
        .slice(0, -1)
        .map(k => typeof event[k] === 'string' ? '\'' + event[k] + '\'' : event[k])
        .join(',');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good answer :), Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply,

```js
 var event = {
  "temperature" : 12.45,
  "humidite" : 45.78,
  "built" : "charone",
  "fire" : "chartwo",
  "topic" : "sk1_001/data"
 };
 
var keys = Object.keys(event);
 
 valeurs_d = ""; 
 for (var i = 0; i < keys.length -1 ; i++) 
 valeurs_d += "\'" + event[keys[i]]+ "\'" + ", "; 
 var str5 = ","; 
 var str6 = str5.concat(valeurs_d); 
 var valeurs = str6.substring(0, str6.length - 2);  console.log(valeurs);
```

Just escape those single quotes and concatenate them to your values.

If you want a double quote in your string, then use `"\""` instead of `"\'"`.

Comment: Nice answer Shiva guy... plus one

Comment: thank you, and if I want : ,12.45, 45.78, 'charone', 'chartwo' ? 

How I proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the quotes directly into the string that you are building, like in this example:

```js
var event = {
  "temperature": 12.45,
  "humidite": 45.78,
  "built": "charone",
  "fire": "chartwo",
  "topic": "sk1_001/data"
};

var keys = Object.keys(event);

var valeurs_d = "";
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
  valeurs_d += "'" + event[keys[i]] + "', ";
}
  
console.info(valeurs_d);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a recent version of most major browsers, you can just use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
var event = {
  "temperature" : 12.45,
  "humidite" : 45.78,
  "built" : "charone",
  "fire" : "chartwo",
  "topic" : "sk1_001/data"
 };
 
console.log(Object.values(event));
```

If you really want the numbers as strings too, change the last line to `console.log(Object.values(event).map(value => String(value)))`.

And if you need the initial comma, just add it: `', ' + Object.values(event).map(value => String(value))`.

Comment: A little more... to quote those numbers too. Perhaps a pre step to convert the numbers to a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

valeurs_d += event[keys[i]] + ", ";

for this one

valeurs_d += "'" + event[keys[i]] + "', ";

Comment: This does not answer the question. _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to change their code without any context or meaning does **not** help them learn what they did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this if it is a string:

```
var str = "chartwo"
var str_with_qoutes =  "'" + str + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly, you can use `Object.values()`, `Array.prototype.join()` with parameter `"','"`, template literal

```js
 var event = {
  "temperature" : 12.45,
  "humidite" : 45.78,
  "built" : "charone",
  "fire" : "chartwo",
  "topic" : "sk1_001/data"
 };
 
 var valeurs = `",'${Object.values(event).join("','")}'"`;
 
 console.log(valeurs);
```